# What percentage of questions here are also on-topic on Cross Validated?

Tags: discussion, scope, cross-validated, questions

I wonder if anyone has tried to approximate the percentage of questions posted here that are also on-topic on Cross Validated.

Comment: Not sure anyone did.  So, by all means, please go ahead with the analysis if you're willing to.  [Now that, DS SE is also very close to coming out of beta] :)

Comment: [Helpful Link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273720/302377)

Comment: @Dawny33 thanks!